# Excel editing formula switch between edit mode and point mode

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

My question is say you are editing a formula in Excel, sometimes pressing the arrow keys means you move to another cell (and thereby include the cell in your formula), whereas other times you move the cursor within the formula.

Is there a way to control this or change between modes?

Comment: Press F2 and pay attention to the status bar in lower left corner. It will tell whether you are in "enter", "point" or "edit" mode. "Enter" and "point" work similarly and will change the formula when you use the arrow keys. "Edit" mode simply moves the cursor in the formula text.

Comment: Ah! And you can just change between "enter" and "edit" by pressing F2. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I should have mentioned F2 cycles the modes (^:

Comment: @andyholaday - This is the answer, I would post it as an answer for the OP to be able to upvote and accept.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Press F2 and pay attention to the status bar in lower left corner. It will tell whether you are in "enter", "point" or "edit" mode. "Enter" and "point" work similarly and will change the formula when you use the arrow keys. "Edit" mode simply moves the cursor in the formula text. Pressing F2 repeatedly will cycle between "edit" and one of the other modes.